# Appending issue in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `Ci`. I am performing an operation within a loop and appending the values. But I am not able to obtain the expected output. How do I fix it?

```
arCi=[]
Ci=[1.0]


for i in range(0,4):
    Ci=Ci[0]*i
    arCi.append(Ci) 
    Ci=list(arCi)
print(Ci)
```

The current output is

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

The expected output is

```
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `Ci=Ci[0]*i`, what do you think this means? What do you think will be the value of `Ci[0]` right before this code runs, each time? Therefore, what result will be calculated? (Hint: what will happen to `Ci` when we do `Ci=list(arCi)`? Therefore, what will be in `Ci` after the first time that the loop runs?)

Comment: Please read [ask] and keep in mind that we do not offer a debugging service. Before posting, [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [study what the code actually does](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), step by step, and think carefully about the logic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the first iteration, when `i=0`, you make the first term of `Ci` as `0.0` and then you are using `0.0` iteratively which gives the answer as `0.0`.

```
Ci = []
num = 1.0


for i in range(0,4):
    Ci.append(num*i)
print(Ci) #yields correct result
```